# how to add ', [] regex special characters in flutter

Tags: regex, forms, validation, flutter, dart

I've making signup form screen

I made Regex patterns

```
    Pattern pattern =
        r'^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[*".!@#$%^&(){}:;<>,.?/~_+-=])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,30}$';
```

problem is if i add ' , [ ] it doesn't work.

if I add ' error occurs in Android studio ( \ escape doesn't work )
[image]

if I add  [ , ] , \ , = , |  these character , error doesn't occurs in AS but validation doesn't work in AVD and console says

```
The following FormatException was thrown while handling a gesture:
Unterminated character class^(?=.*[*.!@#$%^&(){}:;<>,?/~_+-=\]).{8,30}$
```

How can I fix this??

Comment: what is that you want to put in regex ? May be we can simplify the regex

Comment: i'm not so sure about your question but my answer is 
I wanna password combination regex 
1 english character
1 special character
1 digit 
at least with those combination 8~30 characters.
so i can't simplify, could simplify with /w,/d but actually, i wanna focus on special characters cuz that's what problem occurs 

hope you understand my broken

Comment: There is a metacharacter `\W` - Which represents any non-word char to match special characters. For example this - `^(?=[A-Za-z].*?[\d]{1,}.*?[\W]{1,}).*$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to solve this by concatenating your regex

```
Pattern pattern = r'^(?=.*[a-zA-Z])(?=.*[*".!@#\$%^&(){}:;<>,.\' + r"'?/~_+-=])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,30}\$";
```